# Domain registration email not in bailiwick to prevent in case of domain hijacking. How to do it without using personal email?

Tags: security, domain, domain-registration

In the part II of the [blog posts serie on Good practices for the registration and administration of domain portfolios](https://www.icann.org/en/blogs/details/good-practices-for-the-registration-and-administration-of-domain-name-portfolios-part-i-30-5-2017-en), ICANN mentions these good practices:

- Don't use personal email for registration
- Avoid Having Domain Names In-Bailiwick (This means registering domain example.com with email admin@example.com)

An attacker hijacking the domain example.com would also control the email used to register it making it very difficult to get the domain back.

Using a personal email like Gmail is not a good practice if, for example, something happened to the owner of that personal email account.

So, in my understanding, this means a second domain ("example2.com") must be used to register domain "example.com" with admin@example2.com. But then, what email address should be used to register "example2.com"? If we use admin@example.com, the attacker of "example.com" could also get control of domain "example2.com" and the control the emails of "example2.com" domain and then the emails of "example.com" emails too...

I thought maybe using an external DNS server could solve this problem but if the attacker hijacks a domain, he can redirect the DNS anyway.

So how can we setup a registration with two domains that would help in case of a domain hijack like ICANN good practices recommends?

Is the answer to just keep domain "example2.com" secret and make it never show in WHOIS of "example.com"?

This is related to an [older question I posted](https://serverfault.com/questions/1139607/email-account-to-use-for-company-domain-registration-account) about if a second domain should used for registration. I am now more specifically asking how to set it up properly.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `Using a personal email like Gmail is not a good practice if, for example, something happened to the owner of that personal email account.` don't use a personal Gmail account. Create a separate Gmail account just for this purpose at the business.

Comment: I am not sure if Google accounts required to use Gmail must be personnal accounts. I will look in the conditions...

Comment: How would Google know? Or any other email provider? Just create a new businessname986@yahoo.com

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I think a security auditor might not like that we use personnal email to secure domain. What do you think about this?

Comment: Then have your law firm setup an email address your company can use for backup comms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply again. I did not know law firms could do that. Nice to know!